# $\varphi(x,n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor$ and $\sum_{d|n}\varphi\left(\frac xd,\frac nd\right)=\lfloor x\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

> If $x$ is real, $x\ge 1$, let $\varphi(x,n)$ denote the number of positive integers less than or equal to $x$ that are relatively prime to $n$. Prove that
> $$\varphi(x,n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor$$
> and
> $$\sum_{d|n}\varphi\left(\frac xd,\frac nd\right)=\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Since it is clear that $\varphi(n,n)=\varphi(n)$, we can put $x=n$ and check that the identities indeed work.

I guess, the first one will somehow require writing $\varphi(n)$ as a sum over the $x$'s of $\varphi(x,n)$. And once the first one is done, I guess the second one will somehow follow from Möbius inversion formula. But, I am not sure about either. I also couldn't make any more progress.

As I mentioned in the comments, [the duplicate question mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84123/two-identities-on-number-theory) doesn't have a proper complete answer. In particular, none of the two answers has a proof for the second identity. I really want a complete proof of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Identities on Number Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84123/two-identities-on-number-theory) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cvarphi(x%2Cn)%3D%5Csum_%7Bd%7Cn%7D%5Cmu(d)%5Cleft%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%20xd%5Cright%5Crfloor%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bd%7Cn%7D%5Cvarphi%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%20xd%2C%5Cfrac%20nd%5Cright)%3D%5Clfloor%20x%5Crfloor%24&p=1).

Comment: @JohnOmielan this one wasn't suggested to me, and I didn't check Approach0. But still, none of the answers here are actually complete. I'm not sure, I understand the second answer here.

Comment: It seemed the second answer there, although sparse on details, did provide an outline on how to solve the $2$ parts (and note that answer was accepted by the OP). Nonetheless, I agree that those answers are not as complete as they could (and perhaps should) be, so I've retracted my close vote (but I've left my comment as a reference to the other question). Actually, if you get a particularly good answer here, it might make more sense to close that other question as a duplicate of this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity

$$
\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)=
\begin{cases}
1 & n=1 \\
0 & n>1
\end{cases}
$$

so that

$$
\varphi(x,n)=\sum_{\substack{k\le x\\(k,n)=1}}1=\sum_{k\le x}\sum_{d|(n,k)}\mu(d)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\sum_{\substack{k\le x\\d|k}}1=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac xd\right\rfloor.
$$

Applying [Möbius inversion for general convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations) to the right hand side shall give the second identity.

Comment: I can't see how to apply that to find the second expression

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt for the second identity-

Let
$$S_x=\{1,2,\dots \lfloor x\rfloor\}\\
A_{x,n}(d)=\{k\in S_x: (k,n)=d\}$$

So, the $\{A_{x,n}(d)\}$ partitions $S_x$ which gives $\sum_{d|n}|A_{x,n}(d)|=\lfloor x\rfloor$. Also,
\begin{align*}
|A_{x,n}(d)|&=|\{0<k\le x: (k,n)=d\}|\\
&=|\{k/d:0\le k/d\le x/d, (k/d,n/d)=1\}|\\
&=|\{0\le q\le x/d: (q,n/d)=1\}|\\
&=\varphi(x/d,n/d)
\end{align*}
So,
$$\sum_{d|n}\varphi\left(\frac xd, \frac nd\right)=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$$
hence completing the proof.